# python : get specific value from json string

Tags: python, json

I Need to Exact Value from Json response
how can I get a specific json value python ???

this is my Json string
I need to extract  **Id** value

```
"window.__store__ ="{
 "listingReducer":{
    "selectedListing":{
         "id":2234588,
         "has_video":0,
         "refresh":1625551240,
         "category":6,
         "ketchen":1,
         "lift":1,
         "livings":1,
         "maid":null,
         "meter_price":null,
         "playground":null,
         "location":{
            "lat":26.378031,
            "lng":50.124866
         },
         "views":6075,
      },3

}
}
```

this my python code :

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver


jsonScript =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/script[6]")
jsonText = jsonScript.get_attribute('innerHTML')

.
.
.

json_str = json.dumps(jsonText)
resp = json.loads(json_str)
#print (resp)
print(resp[0]['listingReducer']['selectedListing']['id'])

.
.
.
```

And this is the **Error**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Your sample is not JSON string. Then `jsonTEXT` is probably strings, so dumping it and the loading back again will not work. Even if you remove  `"window.__store__ ="` and then the rest is still not valid JSON. There is trailing comma after 6075 and some free-floating 3

Comment: I got it , thank you , so ther is someway  to change the structer of my string to json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is not in JSON format.

I have managed to convert it into JSON by removing irrelevant content (that doesn't follow JSON encoding).

This code will get you the **ID** from the JSON string.

```
import json
s = '''
{
   "listingReducer":{
      "selectedListing":{
         "id":2234588,
         "has_video":0,
         "refresh":1625551240,
         "category":6,
         "ketchen":1,
         "lift":1,
         "livings":1,
         "maid":null,
         "meter_price":null,
         "playground":null,
         "location":{
            "lat":26.378031,
            "lng":50.124866
         },
         "views":6075
      }
   }
}
'''

d = json.loads(s)
print(f"ID: {d['listingReducer']['selectedListing']['id']}")
```

```
Output:

ID: 2234588
```

Comment: thank you , so  is there a way  to change the structure of my string to json format (I mean how to delete the first line)